# SQL returning info not stored in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables Treatment and Prescription.

Treatment contains the patient_no, reason etc.

Prescription contains the Patient_no, drug_code etc.

Want I want to do is return the reason from the treatment table where the patient_ID isnt contained in the prescription table, in other words Returning patients who have been treated who have not been given a prescription.

I have tried this and another numerous combinations and not getting the required results.

```
Select Treatment.Reason
From Treatment LEFT OUTER JOIN Prescription
ON Treatment.Patient_No = Prescription.Patient_No
```

Any pointers or directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly have it correct with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. To find patients with no prescription, look for `NULL`s in the prescriptions column:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT Treatment.Reason
FROM
   Treatment 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Prescription ON Treatment.Patient_No = Prescription.Patient_No
WHERE Prescription.Patient_No IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, just need to remove one duplicate from it but i will have a go at that.

Comment: @user445714 Sure, just `SELECT DISTINCT Treatment.Reason` to dedupe it.